# How to observer a property in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to observe property value in SwiftUI.
I know some basic publisher and observer patterns. But here is a scenario i am not able to implement.

```
class ScanedDevice: NSObject, Identifiable {

    //some variables
    var currentStatusText: String = "Pending"

}
```

here CurrentStatusText is changed by some other callback method that update the status.

Here there is Model class i am using

```
class SampleModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published  var devicesToUpdated : [ScanedDevice] = []
}
```

swiftui component:

```
struct ReviewView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: SampleModel
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(model.devicesToUpdated){ device in
            Text(device.currentStatusText)
        }
    }
}
```

Here in UI I want to see the real-time status

I tried using publisher inside ScanDevice class but sure can to use it in 2 layer

Comment: Change ScannedDevice to a struct

Comment: i can't as there are some other inheritance happing in there i just posted my question idea

Comment: @loremipsum also can you explain how does that solve my problem

Comment: The only SwiftUI wrappers that work for reference types are the ones that end in “Object” the rest need a value type. The reference type  has to be an ObservableObject and the variables need Published. struct makes it a value type therefore can be observed by your setup.

Comment: You will not be able to observe a class without the appropriate setup. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Answer (score 1):

You can observe your `class ScanedDevice`, however you need to manually use a `objectWillChange.send()`,
to action the observable change, as shown in this example code.

```
class ScanedDevice: NSObject, Identifiable {
    var name: String = "some name"
    var currentStatusText: String = "Pending"
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class SampleViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published  var devicesToUpdated: [ScanedDevice] = []
}

struct ReviewView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewmodel: SampleViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 33) {
            ForEach(viewmodel.devicesToUpdated){ device in
                HStack {
                    Text(device.name)
                    Text(device.currentStatusText).foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Button("Change \(device.name)") {
                    viewmodel.objectWillChange.send()  // <--- here
                    device.currentStatusText = UUID().uuidString
                }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewmodel = SampleViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ReviewView(viewmodel: viewmodel)
            .onAppear {
               viewmodel.devicesToUpdated = [ScanedDevice(name: "device-1"), ScanedDevice(name: "device-2")]
            }
    }
}
```